# need to display time using pointer

Tags: c

In the following code I am trying to display clock time, which I get using other functions.
While calling this function from main I am passing addresses in hexadecimal form to this function, and I want to print the time, but it is not printing correctly.

```
void DS1307_GetTime(unsigned char *h_ptr, unsigned char *m_ptr, unsigned char *s_ptr)
{
    I2C_Start();    // Start I2C communication          
    DS1307_Write(DS1307_ID);    // connect to DS1307 by sending its ID on I2c Bus
    DS1307_Write(SEC_ADDRESS);  // Request Sec RAM address at 00H   
    I2C_Stop(); // Stop I2C communication after selecting Sec Register

    I2C_Start();    // Start I2C communication
    DS1307_Write(0xD1); // connect to DS1307( under Read mode) by sending its ID on I2c Bus  

*s_ptr = DS1307_Read();  I2C_Ack(); // read second and return Positive ACK 
*m_ptr = DS1307_Read();  I2C_Ack(); // read minute and return Positive ACK
*h_ptr = DS1307_Read();  I2C_NoAck();   // read hour and return Negative/No ACK

*s_ptr = bcd_to_dec(*s_ptr);
*m_ptr = bcd_to_dec(*m_ptr);
*h_ptr = bcd_to_dec(*h_ptr);

printf("Time is in ss:mm:hh =  %u:%u:%u\n", s_ptr, m_ptr, h_ptr);

I2C_Stop(); // Stop I2C communication after reading the Time   
}
```

I think my problem is in my pointer declaration or printf statement, but I can't figure out exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dereference the pointers in printf. Right now you're printing the pointer values (i.e. addresses) of s_ptr, m_ptr, and h_ptr.

`printf("Time is in ss:mm:hh =  %u:%u:%u\n", *s_ptr, *m_ptr, *h_ptr);`

(This is, of course, assuming your other internal time generating functions are working as intended)

Comment: I have also tried                                                   printf("Time is in ss:mm:hh = %p:%p:%p\n", *s_ptr, *m_ptr, *h_ptr); but still not getting right answer..

Comment: Then I assume your problem is elsewhere. Either in communication with the device or in bcd_to_dec